# Nutiteq set layer level or height

Tags: position, coordinates, android-mapview, nutiteq

i have a map application. In my map, there is two layer which i use. First layer shows traffic lines, second layer shows my route. In this point when i draw route somewhere, my route lines remain below the traffic lines. So i want to set height or level my route layer. It have to allways top of traffic lines.
I try to set z point of my mappos but it couldn't. Is there another way to set height my layer?

```
MapPos mapPos = new MapPos(longitudeValue, latitudeValue, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Drawing order is determined by **adding order of Layers**, so you should use different layers for traffic and route, and add traffic Layer before route Layer. Within single Layer the order of objects is not determined.

Z value is not in use in current version, this is meant for 3D cases, like display of pipelines below ground, or airways above ground. However, the public version does not render basic vector objects in 3D, only 3D models are supported.